# Yukawa potential in higher dimensions

Tags: field-theory, fourier-transform, regularization

I am trying to calculate the integral
\begin{align}
E_n(\mathbf{r}) = \int \frac{d^n \mathbf{k}}{(2\pi)^n} \frac{ e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} }{ \mathbf{k}^2 + m^2 }
\end{align}
for $n > 2$ (the case $n=3$ is well-known and calculated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory#Yukawa_Potential:_The_Coulomb_potential_with_mass)).
Related is [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/331098/yukawa-potential-in-3-dimensional-spacetime) where it is stated that for $n \neq 2$ this should be proportional to $e^{-m r}/{r^{n-2}}$. This intuitively makes sense (as a screened version of the $n$ dimensional Coulomb potential). However, when I perform the integrations, I don't seem to be able to produce this result. One thing to note is that, similar to the Fourier transform of a Coulomb potential ([post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462483/divergent-coulomb-integrals-in-superfluid-fluctuations)), this integral may formally diverge, but one can still obtain finite results by regularizing it.

Trying to generalize the steps outlined in the Wiki page, let's use the $n$-dimensional spherical coordinates, where from the $n-1$ angular variables we only need to perform the integration over one because of the symmetry
\begin{align}
E_n (\mathbf{r} ) &= \frac{S_{n-1}}{(2\pi)^n} \int_0^\infty k^{n-1} dk \int_0^\pi \sin^{n-2}(\theta) \, d\theta \, \frac{ e^{i k r \cos(\theta) }}{k^2 + m^2} 
\end{align}

Wolfram says the $\theta$ integral gives a bunch of Bessel functions, but I don't know how to proceed with that.

**Update**
A different approach is to represent the denominator as an exponential integral
\begin{align}
E_n &= \int \frac{d^n k}{(2\pi)^n} e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} 
\int_0^\infty d\alpha \, e^{-\alpha ( \mathbf{k}^2 + m^2 )}\\
&= \int_0^\infty d\alpha \, e^{-\alpha m^2} \, \frac{ e^{-\frac{\mathbf{r}^2}{4\alpha}}}{(4\pi\alpha)^{n/2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \left( \frac{m}{r} \right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}} \,
K_{\frac{n-2}{2}}(m r),
\end{align}
where from the first to the second line we perform the Gaussian integration and $K$ in the third line is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.
One can now expand the Bessel function for $mr\ll 1$ or $mr\gg 1$; for small distances, substituting the expansion gives a power-law decaying as $r^{-n+2}$, and for large distances, it gives an exponential decay $e^{-mr}$. Although this is very close, but I still can't seem to get the claimed behavior $e^{-mr}/{r^{n-2}}$.

Comment: General tip: [Let's not have posts look like revision histories](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/2451).

Comment: Have you considered the fact that the argument made in the other post is not true? A back of the envelop stationary phase argument seems to show that you are correct, and that asymptotically, you have $\exp(-mr)/r^{(n-1)/2}$.

Comment: @Adam shouldn't the limit of $m\to 0$ give the Coulomb potential?

Comment: @SaMaSo can this help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/562908/how-to-derive-the-2d-asymmetric-form-of-free-green-function-at-large-distance ?

Comment: @SaMaSo you can obtain the desired asymptotic behavior in the limit of $r\gg 1/m$, which can be done with help of the steepest descent of the integral over $\alpha$

Comment: @SaMaSo As explained by Artem Alexandrov, you do recover the Coulomb potential in the limit $m\to 0$. It is just that in the limit $r\gg 1/m$, you do not get $\exp(-mr)/r^{n-2}$ but $\exp(-mr)/r^{(n-1)/2}$, which is identical only for n=3! The reason, as can be deduced from Artem's answer, is that the limit $r\gg 1/m$ for $m=0$ is never reached for any finite $r$ (even very large), and the powerlaw behavior is thus modified.

Comment: @Adam I just can't imagine how the exponent can suddenly jump from $(n-1)/2$ to $n-2$ when $m$ is lowered. Otherwise I understand the mathematical reasoning.

Comment: @SaMaSo it is not a jump, it is a crossover from one powerlaw to the other as $r$ increases above $1/m$. For $m=0$, it never happens, and you just get Coulomb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us start from the integral
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}d\alpha\,\alpha^{-n/2}\exp\left(-\frac{\alpha m^2}{2}-\frac{r^2}{2\alpha}\right).$$
We are interested in the limit of large $r$, so the integral saturates around one point. In order to find this point, we write
$$\alpha^{-n/2}=\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}\ln \alpha\right),$$
so we have the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}d\alpha\,e^{+f(\alpha)},\,\,f(\alpha)=-\frac{n}{2}\ln\alpha-\frac{\alpha m^2}{2}-\frac{r^2}{2\alpha}.$$
As was mentioned, the integral saturates near the point $f'(\alpha_0)=0$, which is (in the limit of large $r$) $\alpha_0=r/m$. Then,
$$f(\alpha_0)=-mr-\frac{n}{2}\ln(r/m),\quad f''(\alpha_0)=-m^3/r.$$
The value of the integral $I$ is
$$I\approx \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{|f''(\alpha_0)|}}e^{f(\alpha_0)},$$
which is
$$\boxed{I\sim \frac{e^{-mr}}{r^{(n-1)/2}}.}$$
It seems that the final expression correctly reproduces screened Coulomb law in 3D,
$$n=3\rightarrow I\sim\frac{e^{-mr}}{r}$$

Additional question is what about case of $m=0$? In case of $m=0$, we have
$$\alpha_0=\frac{r^2}{n},\quad f''(\alpha_0)=-\frac{n^3}{2r^4},$$
so
$$\left.I\right|_{m=0}\sim \frac{1}{r^{n-2}}$$
and coincides with usual Coulomb law.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting approach. It seems that it only reproduces the Coulomb potential for $n=3$. But I thought it should be able to do so in all dimensions?

Comment: @SaMaSo I belive that my result is correct in an arbitrary dimension. As was mentioned by Adam, it seems that in your question there is a typo in asymptotic behavior

Comment: I see that. But I'm still confused why the limit of $m \to 0$ does not reproduce the Coulomb potential in arbitrary dimensions

Comment: @SaMaSo because you should consider this limit in the first line of derivation. I have updated my answer

Comment: One can also do a similar analysis starting from the OP's first equation, and obtain the same result!

Comment: @Adam yes, I just would like to avoid using of special functions

Comment: Am‌ I right to think that the full answer (without performing a saddle approximation) should interpolate between $e^{-mr}/r^{(n-1)/2}$ and $1/r^{n-2}$ by changing $m$ ?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov What I meant is that one can do your analysis not using the integral over $\alpha$ but over $\bf{k}$ (without introducing special functions). It is more cumbersome (since there are $n$ variables$, but works the same way. I'm definitely not saying that it is better than your approach ;-)